# Tor Middlebox: How to check if there is a DNS leak?

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, tor

I created a tor middlebox. Laptop plus WLAN. Creates a WLAN AP all traffic from that AP should be routed into tor. But I am not sure, if the DNS requests are not leaked.

How can I check that? This should be done by a machine connected to the tor-WLAN.

my iptables list:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

my torrc:

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.42.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 192.168.42.1
```

I checked on dnsleaktest.com and the test does not finish on a laptop connected to the torified WLAN.

Comment: I indented the torrc and iptables list by 4 spaces. why isnt there a code block?

Comment: You needed an extra line between the unindented lines and the codeblocked line